# Lossy logging, also get some messages after an error?

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration

Lossy logging in log4net is great to get the details of events leading to an error with minimal performance-loss. However it would often be interesting to also log a few messages **after** the error to verify that the system handled it as planned. How can it be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would write a custom version of the [BufferingForwardAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.BufferingForwardingAppender.html), which would log a configurable number of message after an error. Basically you turn off "being lossy" after an error for a while and forward all messages directly.

Note: Make sure that the appender flushes the messages immediately when an error is logged because you cannot be sure that there will be other messages after the error.

Comment: Thanks, good suggestion, toggeling Lossy was all that was needed. I posted the code in an answer.

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer worked like a charm. To simplify I did not make a separate setting for the number of messages after the error. Instead one full buffer + 1 is sent non-lossy after a triggering message. The code:

```cs
public class BufferingForwardingAppenderEx : BufferingForwardingAppender
{
    /// <summary>
    /// If in lossy-mode, set the appender to non-lossy after a send has been done to get what happended after.
    /// </summary>
    public bool NonLossyAfterTriggered { get; set; }

    // Flag that tells if the appender is currently in non-lossy-override-mode
    private bool _nonLossyOverride = false;

    protected override void SendBuffer(global::log4net.Core.LoggingEvent[] events)
    {
        if (NonLossyAfterTriggered)
        {
            SetLossyAccordingToReasonForSending(events);
        }

        base.SendBuffer(events);
    }

    private void SetLossyAccordingToReasonForSending(LoggingEvent[] events)
    {
        if (_nonLossyOverride)
        {
            var newestEvent = events[events.Length - 1];
            var bufferIsSentBecauseItIsFull = !Evaluator.IsTriggeringEvent(newestEvent);

            if (bufferIsSentBecauseItIsFull)
            {
                _nonLossyOverride = false;
                Lossy = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            _nonLossyOverride = true;
            Lossy = false;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is an example of how it is configured:

```xml
<appender name="BufferingForwardingAppender"
          type="Foo.log4net.BufferingForwardingAppenderEx">
  <bufferSize value="3"/>
  <lossy value="true"/>
  <nonLossyAfterTriggered value="true" />
  <evaluator type="log4net.Core.LevelEvaluator">
    <threshold value="WARN"/>
  </evaluator>
  <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
</appender>

<appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern
      value="%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5level %-13logger{1} %message%newline"/>
  </layout>
</appender>

<root>
  <level value="DEBUG"/>
  <appender-ref ref="BufferingForwardingAppender"/>
</root>
```

With this configuration a lone warning (or worse) is preceeded by 2 and followed by 4 messages.